# Phonegap Build is failing due to dependency error

Tags: phonegap-build

Im building the Phonegap App using Phonegap Build.
Phonegap Build cant create Android APK, build is failing with below error, Morning I was able to create the APK but now below error is thrown. Note that there is no config file changes between morning and now.

Please help 
App Id: 2074580
https://build.phonegap.com/apps/2074580/builds

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.

> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
>     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
>     file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/suppo rt-v4-23.4.0.pom
>     file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/suppo rt-v4-23.4.0.jar
>     file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/suppor t-v4-23.4.0.pom
>     file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/suppor t-v4-23.4.0.jar
>     Required by:
>     :project:unspecified

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with this plugin. I needed to update some android libraries. This command solved it all for me:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"
```

If you don't have the android command in your command line, you can navigate to the SDK directory.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here; https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/928. You need to switch back to Cordova version 1.6.3 or 1.6.4. But I just checked and upgrading to the latest nightly build also seems to fix it. When working in Visual Studio, clear the cordova cache too (after setting the correct version):

Tools => Options => Tools for Apache Cordova => Clear Cordova Cache.